# Multithreading in microcontrollers

Tags: c, multithreading, microcontroller

I have a **`volatile unsigned char array LedState[5]`** variable which is shared between threads. Each index in the array denotes a state. According to each state, the LED will flash in different sequences. One thread sets the state in the array and another thread based on the array index will flash the LEDs.

```
void TurnOnled(state) {
   LedState[state] =1;
}
void TurnOffLed(state) {
   LedState[state] = 0;
}
int CheckLedState(state) {
   return LedState[state]? 1 : 0;
}
Thread 1
---------
TurnOnLed(3);
/*Set of instructions*/
TurnOffLed(3);

Thread 2
--------
if (CheckLedState(3)) {
   /*Flash LEDS according to state*/
else {/*do nothing*/}
```

The problem I have is sometimes in thread 1, I need to `TurnOnLed` and `TurnOffLed` immediately. How can I ensure Thread 2 sees the `TurnOnLed` before  `TurnOffLed` gets called. The above is just a simple example but in reality the LedState variable is set and unset from more than one thread. But no same state is set by different threads.

Comment: You have to use a semaphore per LED that the Set function sets and the read functions turns off once it got the state. The set function should only change the state when the semaphore is clear.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I have just edited my question. I set the states of LedState from more than one thread. I set different states not the same state. As per your idea, if I lock the resource with a semaphore, the other threads trying to set the state will not be able to access it.

Comment: When asking about multithreading, always describe the OS and architecture you are intending to use. While your question can be answered on a theoretical basis assuming multicore and whatnot, it remains open if you will face the problems you are getting the solution for, at all.

Comment: Thanks Vroomfondel for pointing out. I am newbie to posting problems. I am working on a STM32 microcontroller and with a free RTOS running to schedule the tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a semaphore per LED that the Set function sets and the read functions turns off once it got the state. The set function should only change the state when the semaphore is clear. For example:

```
char LedState[5];
char LedSema [5];

void TurnOnled(state) {
   while (LedSema[state]) { /* wait until earlier change processed */ ; }
   LedState[state]= 1;      /* turn LED on */
   LedSema [state]= 1;      /* indicate state change */
}
void TurnOffLed(state) {
   while (LedSema[state]) { /* wait until earlier change processed */ ; }
   LedState[state]= 0;      /* turn LED off */
   LedSema [state]= 1;      /* indicate state change */
}
//Thread 1
//---------
TurnOnLed(3);
/*Set of instructions*/
TurnOffLed(3);

//Thread 2
//--------
if (LedSema[3]==1) {
    /* a change occured */
    if (LedState[3]) {
        /* turn on LED */
    }
    else {
        /* turn off LED */
    }
    LedSema[3]=0;  /* indicate change processed */
}
```

Comment: Do I set LedSema[state] =1 in TurnOnLed

Comment: eh..yes. Forgot that! Also in TurnOffled because you want to indicate a state change. Added that in my solution. And CheckLedState is no longer needed.

Comment: I had quite a few errors in my proposed solution. Think I fixed them all now. See the comments.

Comment: I think you have to clear interrupts BEFORE set the semaphore otherwise you do not guarantee that the setting of the semaphore will happen in the correct sequence.